# Will regular Insert and update into database decrease hardware life?

Tags: database

This question might be stupid but what I think is it would **decrease** life of hardware but I don't know what is the extent to which life is decreased if it does and IF it does not **why not**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think so.

It *might* speed up a fault due to electro-migration, but if that fault occurs, it would likely have happened anyway -- it was just a matter of time.

E.g., "In the late 1980s, one line of Western Digital's desktop drives suffered widespread, predictable failure 12–18 months after field usage. Using forensic analysis of the returned bad units, engineers identified improper design-rules in a third-party supplier's IC controller. By replacing the bad component with that of a different supplier, WD was able to correct the flaw, but not before significant damage to the company's reputation." (source: wikipedia electro-migration article)

So if there is an electro-migration fault waiting to happen -- using the hardware more frequently could speed up the fault manifesting itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends. If your database is using SSDs for storage, your storage has an expected life span and an expected number of program erase (P/E) cycles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory

But rather than try to optimize your application to minimize writes, another option to explore is a fault tolerant database that can handle unexpected drive failures without data loss, along with a hardware replacement plan that tracks well ahead of expected SSD lifespan.